# Is it possible to attach event on the *opening* of the context menu?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am developing a WebExtension and as you know it is impossible to inject content script on `chrome://*` pages and `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/*`. I have a buttons in a context menu and for correct UX I would like to drop my item from context menu on such protected page.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked) I can handle click on my context menu item, but looks like no way to check the url of the page on the moment of right mouse click *without trying to inject content script into every page*?

As a workaround I have a code that checks url after click to the menu item.

[image: chrome chromium extensions page context menu WebExtensions]

Comment: Your context menu items won't be displayed in chrome:// pages AFAIK. As for the webstore, use chrome.tabs.onActivated listener and remove or add the context menu items if a webstore tab was activated/deactivated (you'll need a global flag or a state object in chrome.storage.local to remember if the last active tab is/was a webstore).

Comment: Context menu items displayed on the `chrome://` pages - screenshot attached. Thank you for mentioning `chrome.tabs.onActivated` but I think that with such listener my event page will always in memory - it is not worth it.

Comment: Well, there's no other way because chrome.contextMenus.create doesn't support URL exclusions. BTW, you'll have to listen on chrome.tabs.onUpdated too because a tab can be navigated to or from the webstore URL.